# Understanding shifting and logical operations

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I am trying to read the 'size' of an SD card. The sample example which I am having has following lines of code:

```
unsigned char xdata *pchar; // Pointer to external mem space for FLASH Read function;
pchar += 9; // Size indicator is in the 9th byte of CSD (Card specific data) register;

 // Extract size indicator bits;
size = (unsigned int)((((*pchar) & 0x03) << 1) | (((*(pchar+1)) & 0x80) >> 7));
```

I am not able to understand what is actually being done in the above line where indicator bit is being extracted. Can somebody help me in understanding this?

Answer (score 4):

The `size` is made up of bits from two bytes.  One byte is at `pchar`, the other at `pchar + 1`.

`(*pchar) & 0x03)` takes the 2 least significant bits (chopping of the 6 most significant ones).
This result is shifted one bit to the left using `<< 1`.  For example:

```
11011010 (& 0x03/00000011)==> 00000010 (<< 1)==> 00000100 (-----10-)
```

Something similar is done with `pchar + 1`.  For example:

```
11110110 (& 0x80/10000000)==> 10000000 (>> 7)==> 00000001 (-------1)
```

Then these two values are OR-ed together with `|`.  So in this example you'd get:

```
00000100 | 00000001 = 00000101 (-----101)
```

But note that the 5 most significant bits will always be `0` (above indicated with `-`) because they were `&`-ed away:

To summarize, the first byte holds two bits of `size`, while the second byte only one bit.

Comment: Thanks for the example. The summary is a general one or is specific for your example only ?

Comment: @gpuguy The summary applies to all cases you're dealing with.  IAW, the code you supplied takes 2 bits from one byte, and sticks these against 1 bit taken from the other byte; always.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the size indicator, say SI, consists of 3 bits, where `*pchar` contains the two most significant bits of SI in its lowest two bits (`0x03`) and `*(pchar+1)` contains the least significant bit of SI in its highest bit (`0x80`).

Answer (score 1):

The first and second line figure out how to point to the data that you want.

Let's now go through the steps involved, from left to right.

The first portion of the operations takes the byte pointed to by `pchar`, performs a logical AND on the byte and `0x03` and shifts over that result by one bit.

That result is then logically ORed with the next byte `(*pchar+1)`, which in turn is ANDed with `0x80`, which is then right shifted by seven bits. Essentially, this portion just strips off the first bit in the byte and shifts it over by seven bits.

What the result is essentially this:

Imagine `pchar` points to the byte where bits are represented by letters: `ABCDEFGH`.

The first part ANDs with `0x03`, so we are left with `000000GH`. This is then left shifted by one bit, so we are left with `00000GH0`.

Same thing for the right portion. `pchar+1` is represented by `IJKLMNOP`. With the first logical AND, we are left with `I0000000`. This is then right shifted seven times. So we have `0000000I`. This is combined with the left hand portion using the OR, so we have `00000GHI`, which is then casted into an int, which holds your size.

Basically, there are three bits that hold the size, but they are not byte aligned. As a result, some manipulation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
size = (unsigned int)((((*pchar) & 0x03) << 1) | (((*(pchar+1)) & 0x80) >> 7));
```

- Can somebody help me in understanding this?

We have byte `*pchar` and byte `*(pchar+1)`. Each byte consists of 8 bits.
Let's index each bit of `*pchar` in bold: **76543210** and each bit of `*(pchar+1)` in italic: *76543210*.

1.. `((*pchar) & 0x03) << 1` means "zero all bits of `*pchar` except bits 0 and 1, then shift result to the left by 1 bit":

**76543210** --> **xxxxxx10** --> **xxxxx10x**

2.. `(((*(pchar+1)) & 0x80) >> 7)` means "zero all bits of `*(pchar+1)` except bit 7, then shift result to the right by 7 bits":

*76543210* --> *7xxxxxxx* --> *xxxxxxx7*

3.. `((((*pchar) & 0x03) << 1) | (((*(pchar+1)) & 0x80) >> 7))` means "combine all non-zero bits of left and right operands into one byte":

**xxxxx10x** | *xxxxxxx7* --> **xxxxx10***7*

So, in the result we have two low bits from `*pchar` and one high bit from `*(pchar+1)`.